# Angular component doesn't show up

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a webpage, with angular, and make a header with component. For making the files i'm using the `ng g c commons/header` that make the html,scss,ts and .spec.ts files, and modify the app.module.ts file like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HeaderComponent } from './commons/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './commons/footer/footer.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but, when i'm put it in the index.html file, the component html doesen't show up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <meta name="keywords"
    content="" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="Szabó Boldizsár">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="styles.scss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss">
</head>

<body>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</body>

</html>
```

the generic files(what the console command made) is still the same, i didn't modifyd it.
What can be the wrong? I'm using even bootswatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular index.html file have only `app-root` tag like this:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

just put your header & footer in `app.component.html` file, which is parent component wrapper of all components in your application.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't how Angular works : you can't just render your components into a .html file.
As a SPA (Single Page Application), your content is rendered into a container (app-root by default).
It advice you to follow the official Angular [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) to understand how components are rendered into the application.

Comment: could you provide me the link of this video?

Comment: of course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ym_T0mvvc7c

Comment: starting at 8:13 he adds the header and the footer inside the AppComponent, not inside the index.html

Answer (score 0):

**You have to put the selectors of the header and footer component in the template of the AppComponent instead of putting it in Index.html .**

AppComponent is your bootstrap component , as you can see in the @NgModule metadata property .
You can think of the components mentioned in the bootstrap array as the starting point of you angular application . So any other angular components has to be inside those Base components in order to show up.

And also please refer to the official angular tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

## Angular Update

In new versions of Angular the `index.html` must only contain one tag `<app-root></app-root>`